# Linux не могу изменить разрешение экрана и не запускаются fullscreen приложения

Tags: linux, debian, intel

ОС debian 8 
Использую встроеное видеоядро intel 510.

пакет  xserver-xorg-video-intel установлен

```
   $ aptitude search ~i~nmesa
    i A libegl1-mesa                                                                                                                    - free implementation of the EGL API -- runtime
    i   libegl1-mesa-dev                                                                                                                - free implementation of the EGL API -- development files
    i A libegl1-mesa-drivers                                                                                                            - transitional dummy package
    i   libgl1-mesa-dev                                                                                                                 - free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX development files
    i A libgl1-mesa-dri                                                                                                                 - free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
    i A libgl1-mesa-glx                                                                                                                 - free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
    i A libglapi-mesa                                                                                                                   - свободная реализация API GL — разделяемая библиотека
    i A libgles1-mesa                                                                                                                   - free implementation of the OpenGL|ES 1.x API -- runtime
    i A libgles2-mesa                                                                                                                   - свободная реализация программного интерфейса OpenGL|ES 2.x
    i A libgles2-mesa-dev                                                                                                               - free implementation of the OpenGL|ES 2.x API -- development files
    i A libglu1-mesa                                                                                                                    - Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
    i A libglu1-mesa-dev                                                                                                                - Mesa OpenGL utility library -- development files
    i A libopenvg1-mesa                                                                                                                 - free implementation of the OpenVG API -- runtime
    i A libwayland-egl1-mesa                                                                                                            - implementation of the Wayland EGL platform -- runtime
    i A mesa-common-dev                                                                                                                 - Developer documentation for Mesa
    i A mesa-utils                                                                                                                      - Miscellaneous Mesa GL utilities
```

при запуске glxgears вылазит ошибка

**LLVM ERROR: Cannot select: intrinsic %llvm.x86.sse41.pblendvb**

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260591/llvm-error-instead-of-3d-acceleration-in-debian-stable

предлагают обновить ядро. Но похоже, что либо старый процессор без поддержки sse41, либо невено настроен mesa.

Comment: так и сделал,стало норм. хотя в хромиуме все еще тупит декодирование звука.